# LibreOffice Keeps crashing when I start it up?

Tags: unity, freeze, libreoffice

Before the load bar is done it freezes my OS up.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu + LibreOffice?

Comment: Which Java version? Did you try to start from a terminal? If you do so (using `libreoffice`command), are there any errors? Did libreoffice work once before? If yes, does it help starting from the command line using option `-norestore`? What if you rename (just rename, not delete!) the `.libreoffice` directory in your home dir?

Comment: It failed, even using it from the console made it freeze. Hmmm... Really wish it would work cause I need a good writer program for school. And Yes I'm using the latest.

Comment: Have You tried re-installing it? If it wouldn't help - try uninstalling LibreOffice, and installing OpenOffice.org instead.

Comment: I am also getting similar behaviour with LO on Natty Narwhal 64-bit. LO is default install, not updated.  At first I thought it was Firefox causing the system to lock up. After the second freeze I only had Nautilus and LO opened with Calc. The next time, after a reboot, a few operations on Calc locked up the system for the 3rd straight time. Desktop can't be recovered, LO can't be killed. Only reboot is really possible. Never experienced this with OOo before, and I've been a long time OOo user.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem after upgrading to 11.10.
Removing the .libreoffice directory in my home folder worked well. LibreOffice started just fine after that.